# Triggering function refresh when using ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hitting an issue where I need to ensure Google sheets triggers a cell refresh when data changes. For a variety of reasons, the way my sheet is setup, is that I have an ArrayFormula calculation/login in the header of the cell, and that will essentially calculate all the rows beneath it. For simplicity, my equations are ArrayFormula and passing a value such as 'C2:C', which is ultimately saying 'please give me the value of column C for the given row. So I may have something like ArrayFormula(C2:C + 1) - which is really saying 'give me column C of my current row and add one.

Now, the PROBLEM is that I am building a custom function, lets call it Foo, and I want to also pass it 'columnC of the given row' - so lets say now my ArrayFormula looks like this: ArrayFormula(Foo(C2:C)).

The issue is that, I believe, because of the way google sheets tries to smartly cache function calls, it doesnt recognize when a value changes and to recalculate the call. Google sheets sees that 'C2:C' has not changed at all, so it wont refresh it, even if I did actually change the value of column C of that given row.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to better implement this or work around this?

I created a good test case of this with the following google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fCiRSiuII-2vOWJD9LWWkh9qjK0P_dZskofwBYxiZUI/edit?usp=sharing

If you notice, I have two columns, Total Sft and 'Total sqft New'. Both of these should generate the same value. In the first one, I did a manually multiply - eg A2:A*B2:B - which generates the expected result.
In the second column, rather than a manual multiple equation, I created a test function called testFunctionMultiply which does the same thing - multiplies the values.

As you can see the columns show different values, when I would have expected them to match. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The arrayformula does not work on every function. Like the native DGET function for instance. If you modify the function to accept an array then it works as expected. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wz4CQKff8pX0mv6D32nc3zTSZRVGsYMXxQInxgqRETE/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy from your sheet.

**The formula now is:**

```
={"Total Sqft New";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2:A),,testFunctionMultiply(A2:A,B2:B)))}
```

**The script:**

```
function testFunctionMultiply(param1, param2) {
  const arg1 = param1.flat()
  const arg2 = param2.flat()
  const output = []

  for (i = 0; i < arg1.length; i++){
    output.push([Number(arg1[i])*Number(arg2[i])])
  }

  return output
}
```

**TIP:**

Don't use "" as null value. Google apps script will pick this up in .getLastRow() method for example.

```
//Wrong:
=IF(A2 = "","","Not blank"

//Good:
=IF(A2 = "",,"Not blank:
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps me better understand what I'm missing. But one critical problem is with the above, it results in a recalculation on each new row entry, no? Right now I'm running into timeout issues. Any clever solutions to work around that so it only calculates for the new entries?

Comment: That is the principle of the arrayformula. Or modify the script that not returns into a custom function but paste the values in the sheet itself. Then you could rerun this script via a menu/shortcut/button/timer trigger. Then you (or the trigger) runs when you are done adding rows.

Comment: hi Remco - sorry I didnt understand your comment. Can you please re-explain? Since my sheet has thousands of rows, and truthfully I only use arrayformula because of a different integration which needs it so it triggers for a new entry - so usually the calculation truly is a one-time thing and no ned to recalculate for everyone. Need architectural guidance as to how to keep this performant. Thank you.